# WordPress redirect from IP to domain name

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to understand exactly how WordPress works from the perspective of what is set for the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` settings under `Settings -> General` in the admin GUI.

I have a fresh install of `WordPress 4.7.1` on an internal environment with the dedicated IP of `10.1.245.106`

For the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` settings under `Settings -> General` in the admin GUI, I have them both set to `http://www.example.com`

Under `Settings -> Permalinks`, I have it set to `Post name`

The active theme is `Twenty Seventeen`

In the local host file on my machine, I have the following set.

```
10.1.245.106 example.com
10.1.245.106 www.example.com
```

The `.htaccess` file looks like this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I type `10.1.245.106` into my web browser and hit enter, I am taken to `http://10.1.245.106`

I was under the impression that WordPress would use whatever is set in the `Site Address (URL)` setting, and a redirect would take place and take me to `http://www.example.com`.

I actually thought I remember another one of my sites working like that, so I started digging into why it wasn't happening on this new site I was messing around with.

I tried installing a couple different themes from the WordPress themes repository, but that didn't make the redirect work as I was expecting.

I decided to install and active the `Enfold` theme, which is the theme that is currently active on the site that I remember redirecting from the IP to the domain name.

Sure enough, after installing and activating the `Enfold` theme, then typing `10.1.245.106` into my web browser and hitting enter, I am taken to `http://www.example.com`

I even went into the database and changed the values for the `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` settings to `http://www.exampleblahblahblah.com`, then typed `10.1.245.106` into my web browser and hit enter. Sure enough, I was redirected to `http://www.exampleblahblahblah.com`. Nothing rendered though, because I don't have an entry in my local host file for that domain name.

I dug through the `Enfold` theme and see nothing in the theme code that would be doing this redirect!

Am I right in saying that WordPress core DOES NOT do the redirect from IP to domain name that is set in the `Site Address (URL)` setting?

And since I can't find anything in the `Enfold` theme that is doing this redirect, does anyone have any idea how it would be happening when the `Enfold` theme is active, but not when any of the core WordPress themes that are available in the WordPress theme repository are active?

Comment: Wooow....I was half expecting to read what you had for your dinner last night ;-) any ways, my understanding is that it's a custom rewrite rule which is was probably used in the template you mentioned: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Searched all files of the `Enfold` theme, and get zero results for `add_rewrite_rule`

Answer (score 3):

You can always add a conditional rewrite rule to your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10.1.245.106$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Indeed an option, but I would really like to know how it is working without that currently in place.